# Call to a member function getId() on null on Entity

Tags: php, symfony, traits

I have a error saying that,
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null.`

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User as UserEntity;

trait UserAwareTrait
{
    public function getUser(): ?UserEntity
    {
        return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find(UserEntity::class, parent::getUser()->getId());

    }
}
```

I tried this and and several conditions found on other posts in StackOverflow..

```
public function getUser(): ?UserEntity
    {

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $findResult = $user->find(UserEntity::class,parent::getUser());

        if($findResult !== null) {
            return $findResult->getId();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I get this error : `The identifier id is missing for a query of App\Entity\User`

Comment: You might also have a syntax error. Notice the slight difference between these 2 lines? `->find(UserEntity::class, parent::getUser()->getId());` and `->find(UserEntity::class, parent::getUser())->getId();`?

Comment: Sorry it's a copy paste error that I don't have in my code. I edited my question thanks! @TimLewis

Comment: This function is used at the time of registration. So it does not find the id because the user is not created at that time I think. I'm just trying to make a condition "if userId is null" but I can't write it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my code to show what I tried to do @TimLewis

Comment: This entity is more than 1000 lines ... :/ Here is my find doc :                                 public function ObjectManager::find($className, $id); mixed|null|object
This is just a convenient shortcut for getRepository($className)->find($id).
Parameters:
string
$className
The class name of the object to find.

$id
The identity of the object to find.

Comment: This is Object Manager's find() method , no custom : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21doctrine%21common%21lib%21Doctrine%21Common%21Persistence%21ObjectManager.php/function/ObjectManager%3A%3Afind/8.2.x

Comment: Apologies, I see that now. I didn't read the tags; that's my bad. Thought this was Laravel due to the syntax being pretty close (cleaned up my comments, hopefully someone with Drupal/base symphony knowledge will be able to help moving forward)